# django - filtering via ManyToMany field

Tags: python, django

Let's say I have models like this:

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Topping(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Flavor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    of_topping = models.ForeignKey(Topping, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    on_pizzas = models.ManyToManyField(Pizza)
```

Then, I have topping "Salami" with flavors "spicy", "non-spicy" and "italian", a topping "Fungus" with flavors "Champignon", "Boletus" and "Fly agaric".

A pizza is constrained such that it cannot contain two toppings of the same Topping class but with different flavors. (e.g. there is no Pizza with both italian and spicy salami).

Now, let's say my pizzaria offers those pizzas:

- Margherita (no toppings)
- Salami (non-spicy salami)
- Funghi (Champignon)
- Yummy (italian salami and Champignon)
- Toxic (spicy salami and fly agaric)
- Special (italian salami and Boletus)

Now, for a customer Bob, I know is constraints, e.g. he would eat Champignon and italian salami (but would also eat anything that has only a subset of those as toppings).
For Bob, I would no like to find out, that I could offer him Margherita, Funghi or Yummy.
For each customer, the list of constraints will only include (at most) one flavor per topping. So there would be no customer who says that she likes both spicy and non-spicy salami.

How do I write a filter that does this? Something like

```
Pizza.objects.filter(flavor__??=list_of_flavor_constraints)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is too complex for a single query. It would either require multiple joins or a subquery. I have not tested this but try this:

```
from django.db.models import Subquery

excluded_pizzas = Flavor.on_pizzas.through.objects.exclude(flavor__in=list_of_flavor_constraints).values('pizza')
result = Pizza.objects.exclude(id__in=Subquery(excluded_pizzas))
```

`excluded_pizzas` is a subquery performed on the intermediate m2m table, where we exclude the flavours the user actually wants and select the pizza's id, giving us the pizzas that we actually **don't want**.

Next we actually exclude the ids of these pizzas giving us the pizzas we do want.